# Car audio volume lowers no bass

Tags: audio

I have 2 jl subs 7a8we with amp and 4 focal speakers with jl amp sounds great but when I have volume about midway from time to time I lose subs and my audio I can still barely hear when I lower volume all returns to normal stays for days than happens again

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Audio playing normally but after a while I lose all sound except highs than when I lower volume all sound returns doesn't happen all the time but once in a while for example sound volume at 50 than out of no where I lose base mid range like some one has lowered volume but when I lower volume all returns to normal